# how to fix Trying to get property of non-object in laravel 5.2

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5

in My Laravel 5.2 application I have tasks table like this

```
 id      task_name      project_id
    1         aaa               1
    2         hjhkj             2
    3         jhghg             1
    4         jgsdygu           3
    5         gdggfv            2
```

now I am going to display task names for to relevant each project_id in My index.blade.php file in tasks folder in resource file.

I am using this codes for this

```
@foreach ($project->tasks as $task)
    <h4><a href="/projects/{{$project->id}}/tasks/{{ $task->id }}">{{ $task->task_name }}</a></h4>
@endforeach
```

now I can seen with tasks name relevant to each project_id. but now I need to click on each task name and display project_id, task id and task name in show.blade.php file witch located in task folder

TaskController.php method for this

```
 public function getOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId)
    {
        $task = Task::where('project_id', $projectId)
                      ->where('id', $taskId)
                      ->first();
        return view('tasks.show')->withTask($task)->with('projectId', $projectId);
    }
```

but I got following error message

```
Trying to get property of non-object (View: C:\Users\Lilan\Desktop\prome\resources\views\tasks\show.blade.php)
```

tasks/show.blade.php

```
{{ $task->task_name }}
{{$task->project_id}}

how can fix this problem?
```

My routes

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@getOneProjectTask',

]);
```

Comment: What is your desired output?

Comment: need print task_name, project_id, task id please see updated question

Comment: Show your routes.

Comment: @SreejithBS please see updated question

Answer (score 0):

First make a tasks resource route

`Route::resource('tasks', 'TaskController');`

Use the reverse relationship, in Task model make a function

`public function project(){
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Project', 'project_id');
    }`

and in your href link, give the link of the tasks show `href="{{ $url = route('tasks.show', [$task->id]) }}"` ,

using the reverse relationship, you can get the project id when you pass task object to the view like `{{ $task->project->id }}`.

Comment: what about My allready exit Task Model function  public function project()
  {
         return $this->belongsTo('App\Project');
     }

Comment: Then its fine, you don't need to make another Task model.You just give the foreign key project_id to your Task model function project.

Comment: I guess you are passing the project_id  value in tasks table which is not even there in projects table primary key.

Comment: can you tell me the way passing the primary key

Comment: yes I am passing task table project_id??? what did you mean  which is not even there in projects table primary key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public function getOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId) {

    // dd($projectId);
    // dd($taskId);

    $task = Task::where([
                ['project_id', '=', $projectId],
                ['id', '=', $taskId],
            ])->first();

    // dd($task);

    return view('tasks.show', compact('task', 'projectId'));
}
```

Check if you are getting value using `dd`

Comment: yes in My getOneProjectTask method dd value is working

Comment: whats the result of dd($task); ?

Comment: "1" as print task id

Comment: Comment all dd except dd($task);

Answer (score 0):

this is working
TaskController

```
public function getOneProjectTask($projectId, $taskId)
    {
$task = Task::where('project_id', $projectId)
                      ->where('id', $taskId)
                      ->first();
        return view('tasks.show')->withTasks($task)->with('projectId', $projectId);
    }
```

routes

```
Route::get('projects/{projects}/tasks/{tasks}', [
    'uses' => '\App\Http\Controllers\TasksController@getOneProjectTask',

]);
```

tasks/show.blade.php

```
{{$tasks->task_name}}
```